# Problems updating a record with Entity Framework Core 6

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I am reaching out for your help regarding the following issue. I am using C#, EF Core 6, and MySQL 8, and when I reload a table in a datagrid, the records are displayed normally. However, when I perform a refresh in the datagrid, the following situations occur:

- If I modify a record directly in the database, the update is not reflected in my application.
- If a record is added or deleted from the database, the updates are reflected in the application.
- When I update a record from my application, it is reflected in the database. However, if I have 2 instances of my application open, the other instance cannot reflect the update. But, if I delete or add another instance of my application, the deletion or new record is reflected.

To perform a refresh, I do the following:

```
Context.agenda.load();
Datagrid1.ItemSource = Context.agenda.ToList();
```

I am trying to update a record but in EF Core 6, I am unable to obtain the update. Only the added and deleted records are updated. I want it to reflect all the updates that were made in the table.

Comment: Don't use one context instance. If `Context` is a new instance it will load all data from the database. A context will never overwrite properties of already tracked entities (unless you explicitly reload entities, but you don't want that for a complete refresh).

Comment: Hello @gert arnold, thank you for your response, but what you're trying to tell me is to create a new connection to the database?
`var options = existingContext.GetContextOptions<Context>();
var newContext = new Context(options);`
Could you give me an example if it's not too much trouble?

Comment: You you created `Context`, create a new context likewise if you need fresh data. Note that a context is not the same as a new *connection*.

Comment: Avoiding entities as data containers is a good way to effectively avoid data blocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best advice I can give is *avoid* passing entities as data containers to views/controls. Project to ViewModels containing just the data the view/control needs. This avoids tracked instance issues, as well as can improve querying performance.

For instance, instead of something like:

```
DataGrid.ItemSouorce = Context.Agenda.ToList();
```

use

```
DataGrid.ItemSource = Context.Agenda
    .Select(x => new AgendaSummary
     {
        AgendaId = x.AgendaId,
        Name = x.Name,
        // ... etc for fields the control needs to display or index
     }).ToList();
```

Where AgendaSummary is a POCO class who's purpose is to serve as the data container for a data grid row.

Statements like this will not track any entities meaning each read will effectively go to the DB each time for the latest data state. They can also be faster to run and use less memory since the DB only needs to return the fields used, and all in one hit. This avoids potential lazy load scenarios as well.

An alternative work-around is to always use `AsNoTracking()` to avoid EF getting these tracked references:

```
DataGrid.ItemSouorce = Context.Agenda.AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

This may work, but I'm not sure in cases where you may have loaded and tracked one or more Agenda elsewhere via that same DbContext instance, whether this will still potentially return the tracked entity, ignoring data state changes. For instance if you read a few agendas without `AsNoTracking()` then query the list, it will load all records but it may still give you those few tracked references which could be stale.

Ultimately you should also consider keeping DbContexts alive only as long as they are needed. You don't want to do things like use a Singleton DbContext instance. Spinning up a DbContext instance is fast, though some devs when starting to work with EF experience a situation where the first query against a DbContext is notably slow, so they figure they should keep it open because of a start-up cost... There is a one-off static spin-up costs when a DbContext is first initialized to work through the mapping/config for entities that DbContext will be working with, but that is a single static operation so it will only occur the very first time any instance of that DbContext is queried. Creating additional instances of that DbContext will not incur that spin-up cost within the same process. The longer a DbContext is open, the more entities it tracks and the longer it can take to resolve references to entities, plus develop synchronization issues with the underlying database as it continues to return stale tracked entities rather than fresh copies from the DB.